# Algorithm for most efficient memory write

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have the following problem and need help coming up with an algorithm for it

---

You have value which you must write at a specific address in memory and a counter which starts from 0. The objective is to find the most efficient way to write the value in memory, where efficiency is determined by increasing the counter the least amount possible.

We assume that:

- The computer uses little endianness
- With each write we write 4 bytes at once
- We can only write the contents of the counter to memory, so if the counter is curently 0x7a you'll write 0x7a000000 (remember that we use little endianness)
- We can only increment the counter (one at a time), not decrement it
- We can write to neighbor addresses from the objective address you were given

For example, with the following arguments:

- `address = 0x1000`
- `value = 0x01025544`

The most efficient way to write this would be:

1. Increment counter from 0x0 to 0x44 (0x44 = 68 in base 10)
2. Write counter to memory @ (address). Memory now looks like this: `0x44000000`
3. Increment counter from 0x44 to 0x55 (0x55 = 85 in base 10)
4. Write counter to memory @ (address + 1). Memory now looks like this: `0x44550000`
5. Increment counter from 0x44 to 0x0102 (0x0102 = 258 in base 10)
6. Write counter to memory at (address + 2). Memory now looks like this: `0x44550201`

`0x44550201 -> 0x01025544 == value`, the algorithm finished.

Of course this pseudocode is specific for this case, I want something that's generic and works for any value, not just this one.

Comment: The lack of answers and even comments 15 hours after posting means readers do not understand your question. In fact, their understanding is so poor that they have difficulty framing questions to ask. At the same time I think there might be at least a glimmer of interest if you could clarify your question. As a start consider giving a second example that illustrates a different situation. Also, please clarify "increasing the counter the least amount possible". Is that the same as minimizing the value of the counter at the completion of the process? If so, that wording might be clearer.

Comment: I lost interest in this question when it just looked too trivial. There are at most 8 possible ways to achieve the result, and comparing 8 possible ways doesn't seem rocket science. Most of the work of providing an answer would go into thinking which pseudo code to use for this. So I just left it.